# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload was not handled by any navigator Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native, and i have searched a lot regarding this error. So the issue is that I am creating a simple blog app with wordpress rest api.

So the structure is HOME -> (Loads all the posts) -> (OnPress) -> DETAILS(the single post is shown).

I have two screens on for home and another details.

Using Params i am navigating to the details screen.

The problem is that when i use Stack Navigation/Native Stack Navigation it works.

As i have multiple categories, i do not want to show the "Details Screen" on any of the navigator.

Like for Bottom navigation it should be only "Home". Not the Details Screen as it will return error without any params.

I have tried nested navigation but i think i am doing something wrong.

Here is the code for and screenshots.

RootNavigator.js

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";

import Details from "../screens/Details";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const RootNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default RootNavigator;
```

AppNavigation.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";

import "react-native-gesture-handler";

import { DrawerActions } from "@react-navigation/native";

import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import RootNavigator from "./RootNavigator";



const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: Forgot to mention this is working but - now how can i make Drawer Navigation work ?

`<Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Bottom"
        component={TabNavigation}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Drawer" component={Drawer} />

      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );`

Answer (score 0):

In order to not show the Details page in the bottom tab navigator you need to create a new stack

For example:

HomeNavigator.js

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Details from "../screens/Details";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const HomeNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default HomeNavigator;
```

now in the TabNavigator:

TabNavigator.js

```
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import HomeNavigator from "./HomeNavigator";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeNavigator} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default TabNavigator;
```

Now you can simply navigate from Home to Details:

```
navigation.navigate("Details", YOUR_PARAMS_HERE)
```